# save a text and a value into combobox from a database table

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to take the name and surname of users from the table "EMPLOYE" (SQL DB) and save them in the combobox.
I want to save the ID of each user in the combobox value.
so this is my code =>

```
       public void fill_combobox_users()
    {
        // auto-complete
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID_EMP, concat(NOM_EMP,' ',PRENOM_EMP) as 'nom_prenom' from EMPLOYE", cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "nom_prenom";
            comboBox3.ValueMember = "ID_EMP";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }

    }
```

The full name displayed without problems but the value no !!
The problem is that the combobox3.ValueMember take the string "ID_EMP" not the value from the table EMPLOYE !

ANY SOLUTIONS PLEASE ?

Comment: See `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: Are you using WPF ?

Comment: No I don't @UmairFarooq .. I'm using simple winforms (VS 2015)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your sql query like this. Should work

```
 public void fill_combobox_users()
        {
            // auto-complete
            comboBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            comboBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID_EMP,(NOM_EMP+ ' ' + PRENOM_EMP) AS NOMM from EMPLOYE", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
                comboBox3.DisplayMember = "NOMM";
                comboBox3.ValueMember = "ID_EMP";
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks very much 
But how can I get the value from the combobox .. 
I tried this code to test :
 private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox3.ValueMember.ToString());
        }

But the messagebox appears empty !! without any values

Comment: Use it comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

To get the value try

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Comment: I tried MessageBox.Show(combobox3.SelectedValue.toString());
for each selected item it appears System.Data.DataRowView !

Comment: Try Changing the Order of your combobox binding and Assign DataSource in the end..Do it in this order : 

comboBox3.DisplayMember = "nom_prenom";
comboBox3.ValueMember = "ID_EMP";
comboBox3.DataSource = dt;

Comment: NO NO NO I'm sorry .. my code was wrong !
I wrote combobox1 instead of combobox3 
It work perfectly now .. thanks Bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Column Name is problem you want use Column index see here.

```
 public void fill_combobox_users()
    {
        // auto-complete
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID_EMP,(NOM_EMP+ ' ' + PRENOM_EMP) AS NOMM from EMPLOYE", cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
            comboBox3.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }

    }
```